# Why are my transporterControl methods using getRouteData() and getNumberOfTransporters() erroneous?

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to implement a simple form of transporter routing choice algorithm but I am having some trouble using some of the functions as given by Anylogic help. My model basically just tries to check the number of transporters in the next following path and node and then evaluates accordingly to pick the route. It is not complete as of now but the picture below shows my current implementation:

[image]

While compiling and executing the program, I received 2 errors and hope some advice can be provided.

**Error 1**

Error 1 can be seen in the screen capture above. Why is my function call erroneous?

**Error 2**

I am not too sure why this is happening either. Any advice?

[image]

Appreciate all the help given!

Comment: error 1: the function "getRouteData" is not defined for a unit. Use code-complete and you will see it does not exist there. Figure out how it was originally used to understand where it can and cannot be used